# How to set volume when using `docker stack deploy` swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to save data using volume. It won't restore my data when I `docker stack deploy` it. How do I set volume?

Running `docker stack deploy -c compose-db.yml db`.

This is my compose file.

#### compose-db.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: 172.16.12.154:5000/redis
    networks:
      pitbull-overlay:
        aliases:
          - redis
    volumes:
      - redis-volume:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  mongodb:
    image: 172.16.12.154:5000/mongodb
    networks:
      pitbull-overlay:
        aliases:
          - mongodb
    volumes:
      - mongodb-volume:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

networks:
  pitbull-overlay:
    external:
      name: pitbull-overlay

volumes:
  mongodb-volume:
  redis-volume:
```